# How do I purge Image Cache in ZenPhoto 1.4.5?

Tags: php, zenphoto

In the previous version of Zenphoto I had installed, there was a big button on the overview page 'Purge Image Cache'.  This has now gone.

I need this facility.  Does anyone know where it is now located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found you need to Enable the `cacheManager`plugin.

I don't remember having to do this before, maybe its off by default now.